# Faster way to retrieve data from a specific data table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose we have a data table/entity in MySQL DB. As we know that we can retrieve data from a table using **Primary** key and **Self-Created** key. Now my question is which approach is **faster** to **retrieve** data? Using primary key or self-created key? Then ( if the answer is primary key or self-created key ) why this data **manipulation will be faster**?

Comment: What is a "self-created" key?

Comment: You are asking too trivial questions. If you are genuinely interested in indexing, have a look here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents

Comment: 1) Retrieving data is not data manipulation. 2) I have no idea what a "self-created" key is supposed to be. 3) "Retrieve data" is very broad. There is a difference for instance in whether you select a single record from a table, e.g. an order from an orders table, or all records from a table, e.g. all orders.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use a composite key it will be faster than primary key.

A composite key, in the context of relational databases, is a combination of two or more columns in a table that can be used to uniquely identify each row in the table.

It defines your data. It may be an identity column, it may be a varchar column or a datetime column or an integer column, or it may be a combination of multiple columns. When you define more than one column as your primary key on a table, it is called a composite primary key.

Comment: Why do you state that a "composite key is faster than a primary key"?

Comment: it depends on the complexity of the tables.. sometimes using composite key is faster than primary key !

Comment: I've down-voted. Someone who reads your answer will believe that this is always true, and as your write in the comment, "it depends".

Comment: okay I understand your point of view,
my answer is related to this case !